# Elasticsearch Suggestions as main search method

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it ok to use suggestions as my main method of searching?

Why bother with match, query, etc... when suggestions provide that "fuzzy" search I am seeking?

If I send "canc" to elastic, I get back "Cancer Research", "Cancer Survivors", as I desire.

Are there any flaws in this approach?

I'm using ES 5.0.1

Here is the mapping:

```
{
  "my_search_engine": {
    "mappings": {
      "AVkh9NoKj_akQIGkggtM": {
        "properties": {
          "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "title_suggest": {
            "type": "completion",
            "analyzer": "simple",
            "preserve_separators": true,
            "preserve_position_increments": true,
            "max_input_length": 50
          },
          "url": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "my_company": {
        "properties": {
          "title": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "title_suggest": {
            "type": "completion",
            "analyzer": "simple",
            "preserve_separators": true,
            "preserve_position_increments": true,
            "max_input_length": 50
          },
          "url": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the elasticsearch version you use and the mapping

Comment: It depends on your use case and the fields. What if I am searching for www.g in your url field? Are you going to return me all the www.g websites? Also , what if you have 10k entries on your index that Match "A..." .

Comment: I will only allow you to search the title/tags field(s). The url field are just for clicking to get to that page.